# Nested textview not visible on device, but visible in Design mode

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-3.1.4

The apps top component has 4 TableRows under a TableLayout and each has a nested TextView and a Switch.
Each of these is set to Visibility:visible
And they show as expected in the Design mode for all available resolutions say NexusS(4.0,480x800,hdpi)
but when started on my Marshmallow device of the same resolution and size, only the switches show up and in their correct positions, those 4 textviews dissappear..

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmPqk.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UNBo.png)![on device]

Heres the relevant xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MainPage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bb"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
    android:minHeight="320dp"
    android:minWidth="240dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="205dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:background="#ad000000"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:text="@string/playBtn"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.272"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#ad000000"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:text="@string/setBtn"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/play"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/quit"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#ad000000"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:text="@string/quitBtn"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/settings"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/settings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="178dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/owaw"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="120sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/play"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.418"
        tools:text="@string/app_name" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/OptionsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="100dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Option1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Option2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Option2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Option2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="@string/opt1" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/tutorialSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:allowUndo="true"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:checked="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:showText="false"
                android:splitTrack="false"
                android:switchMinWidth="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Option2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Option3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Option3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Option3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Option1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="@string/opt2" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/musicSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="-70dp"
                android:allowUndo="true"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:checked="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:showText="false"
                android:splitTrack="false"
                android:switchMinWidth="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Option3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Option4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Option4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Option4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Option2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="@string/opt3" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/hapticSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:allowUndo="true"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:checked="false"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:showText="false"
                android:splitTrack="false"
                android:switchMinWidth="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Option4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Option5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Option5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Option5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Option3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="@string/opt4" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/sfxSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:allowUndo="true"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:checked="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:showText="false"
                android:splitTrack="false"
                android:switchMinWidth="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Option5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Option4">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/saveOption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="@string/opt5" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

UPDATE:
I added the font family property to each of those and now the text is visible on device but I dont understand how it matters, since there is already a default option there.

Comment: How is this related to the NDK?

Comment: Unrelated. Just typed in the tag and didnt remove it after that.

Comment: I added the font family property to each of those and now the text is visible on device but I dont understand how it matters, since there is already a default option there.